# Why simplify algorithm has no effect on input in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, vertices, simplify

I have a LineString layer that I need to reduce the number of vertices. For example, some straight lines have intermediate vertices that add no value and should be removed. A slight loss of accuracy, as a result, is acceptable.

To my understanding the Simplify algorithm on QGIS is the perfect tool for this, however, no matter what I do, no vertices are removed when this tool is used. There are no errors in the log, and the execution seemingly succeeds.

What am I doing wrong? A piece I am testing can be downloaded here:
https://easyupload.io/oivzk9

I use QGIS 3.28.0 but tried with 3.4.5 and 2.18.16 on another computer as well. The result is the same.

Comment: Please, specify which QGIS version you are using.

Comment: Ah, right. I use 3.28.0, but tried with 3.4.5 and 2.18.16 on another computer as well. Every time the result is the same. Added this to the main post. It seems like the problem is on my side, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the QGIS version 3.26 the `Dissolve tool` has a new option: [Keep disjoint features separate](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-keep-disjoint-features-separate-option-for-dissolve-algorithm). Check this option; your line features will be reduced from 2,212 to 41 keeping the whole line structure the same.

Input:

[image]

Dissolve tool:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Finally, use the `Simplify tool` to simplify the line and reduce the number of vertices from 1,147 to less than 100. Adjust the tolerance based on your needs.

Before Simplification:

[image]

Simplify tool:

[image]

After Simplification:

[image]

Comment: That does decrease the number of features but they cannot be simplified any better. The result is a multilinestring with lots of two-vertex members. But that is a good start. With the "Merge lines" tool the multilinestrings can be converted into long lines with lots of vertices, and they can finally be simplified.

Comment: @user30184 The new `Keep disjoint features separate` option acts exactly as if you have used the `Merge lines` tool. It creates lines with many vertices connected together (two steps in one step).

Comment: All right, I have only QGIS 3.28.1 at the moment. But the name of the option  might be improved, it does not tell that the new option performs both dissolve/union and merge. Please simplify the result with a tolerance of 1 and tell how many vertices are left on the layer. I have 87 after old dissolve + merge + simplify.

Comment: @user30184 Using the new `Keep disjoint features separate` option + simplify I got 87 vertices. This means the new Dissolve option acts as `dissolve` + `merge lines` together. So it is two steps in one step, as I said in my previous comment

Comment: Are you in position to improve the description of the tool in QGIS? Does automatic merge affect only the "Keep disjoint features separate" option?

Comment: @user30184 No I am not. In fact, the description in the changelog shows an example of using this option with polygons, if you have checked the updated answer. I only have a chance to try this option today for this question.

Comment: Perfect, this is the true solution.

Answer (score 6):

Your data contains 2212 features, each one having exactly two vertices: the start vertex and the end vertex. There is nothing to simplify as your data stand right now.

Comment: You're right, I simply did not understand how this tool works. My intention was to dissolve the layer to fewer multi linestring features and then simplify.

Answer (score 4):

Use Dissolve tool to get one geometry. Then use Simplify tool with `Tolerance:0.5 (m)`. Try different tolerance values and check the results.

Comment: Indeed dissolving geometries correctly was the key here. The other answer explains it in more detail.