# How can I merge polygons in QGIS by attribute only if they are adjacent?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, dissolve

I have a grid with 100 cells classified in deciles of a pollutant concentration. I need to merge polygons from the same decile only if they are adjacent. Someone can help me by pointing me to a function or a plugin?

Answer (score 4):

You can run "Dissolve" by your attribute and then run "Multipart to Singleparts".

Original:
[image]

Dissolve:
[image]

Dissolved:
[image]

Multiparts to Singleparts:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: How about the new option "Keep disjoint features separate" https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-keep-disjoint-features-separate-option-for-dissolve-algorithm in the Dissolve tool? Usage example in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448883/qgis-simplify-algorithm-has-no-effect-on-input/448903#448903